# Getting error in subtraction of floating numbers in PHP. Same code with similar data returns different results

Tags: php

Need to understand this error and resolve it:

```
<?php
$a = 204.95 + 204.95 + 204.95;
$b = 614.85;
echo $a ."->" .$b ."->" . ($b - $a)."\n";


$a = 204.93 + 204.93 + 204.93;
$b = 614.79;


echo $a ."->" .$b ."->" . ($b - $a)."\n";
?>
```

Getting output:

```
614.85->614.85->1.1368683772162E-13
614.79->614.79->0
```

Expected Result is:

```
614.85->614.85->0
614.79->614.79->0
```

Comment: The solution in "Is floating point math broken?" is to use abs(). But in my case I cannot. As this is related to price calculation, the decimal values are really important. I cannot round off or use absolute value.

Comment: IAmMilinPatel: The actual value in your code is https://3v4l.org/11jqT. You need to use `number_format()` with `2` decimal precision: https://3v4l.org/qPscr. Otherwise, you will always get some sort of miscalculation.